# Shuffling an array of objects in java not working properly

Tags: java, arrays, object, shuffle

I have created an array of card objects that I want to shuffle. However, when i use a simple shuffle method, the output is incorrect. Instead of shuffling, it duplicates some cards and deletes others. Here is an example of what it prints

```
Jack of Clubs
5 of Hearts
4 of Hearts
7 of Hearts
5 of Hearts
Ace of Spades
8 of Clubs
5 of Hearts
Jack of Diamonds
Jack of Clubs
Queen of Diamonds
Jack of Diamonds
9 of Diamonds
4 of Hearts
Jack of Diamonds
3 of Diamonds
6 of Diamonds
Jack of Clubs
4 of Hearts
10 of Diamonds
Jack of Diamonds
2 of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
7 of Hearts
5 of Hearts
King of Diamonds
5 of Hearts
9 of Diamonds
Ace of Spades
4 of Diamonds
King of Diamonds
10 of Hearts
9 of Diamonds
2 of Diamonds
10 of Diamonds
5 of Hearts
10 of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
4 of Diamonds
2 of Diamonds
9 of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
10 of Diamonds
7 of Hearts
5 of Hearts
8 of Clubs
4 of Hearts
5 of Hearts
5 of Hearts
5 of Hearts
```

As you can see, there are too many diamonds and barely any clubs or spades. I have also noticed that only the suits are messed up. There are four of every number and four jacks queens kings and aces. Thank you for your help.

Here is the code for the card class:

```
public class Card {
//variables for attributes
private String name;
private String suit;
private int value;

//constructors
public Card(){
}
public Card(String name, String suit, int value){
    this.setSuit(suit);
    this.setValue(value);
    this.setName(name);
}

//getter and setter methods
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}
public void setSuit(String suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}
public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

And here is the code for the deck class:

```
public class Deck {
//array of cards
private Card[] cardArray = new Card[52];

//constructor
public Deck(){
}

//methods to create cards of different suits
public void createClubs(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        cardArray[i]=new Card(Integer.toString(i+2),"Clubs",i+2);
    }
    cardArray[9]=new Card("Jack","Clubs",10);
    cardArray[10]=new Card("Queen","Clubs",10);
    cardArray[11]=new Card("King","Clubs",10);
    cardArray[12]=new Card("Ace","Clubs",1);
}
public void createDiamonds(){
    int j = 2;
    for(int i = 13; i < 22; i++){
        cardArray[i]=new Card(Integer.toString(j),"Diamonds",j);
        j++;
    }
    cardArray[22]=new Card("Jack","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[23]=new Card("Queen","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[24]=new Card("King","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[25]=new Card("Ace","Diamonds",1);
}
public void createHearts(){
    int k = 2;
    for(int i = 26; i < 35; i++){
        cardArray[i]=new Card(Integer.toString(k),"Hearts",k);
        k++;
    }
    cardArray[35]=new Card("Jack","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[36]=new Card("Queen","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[37]=new Card("King","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[38]=new Card("Ace","Hearts",1);
}
public void createSpades(){
    int l = 2;
    for(int i = 39; i < 48; i++){
        cardArray[i]=new Card(Integer.toString(l),"Diamonds",l);
        l++;
    }
    cardArray[48]=new Card("Jack","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[49]=new Card("Queen","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[50]=new Card("King","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[51]=new Card("Ace","Spades",1);
}

//method to get and display attributes of the array
public void displayArray(){
    for(int i = 0; i<cardArray.length;i++){
        System.out.println(cardArray[i].getName() + " of " + cardArray[i].getSuit());
    }
}
public void displayCard(int i){
    System.out.println(cardArray[i].getName() + " of " + cardArray[i].getSuit());
}
public Card[] getArray(){
    return cardArray;
}

//shuffle method
public void shuffle(){
    for(int i = 0; i<cardArray.length; i++){
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * cardArray.length);

        Card temp = cardArray[random];
        cardArray[random] = cardArray[i];
        cardArray[i] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Read your `createHearts` and `createSpades` methods carefully.

Comment: Your approach to shuffle the cars does not seem like a fair shuffle.

Comment: As a general comment about your `Card` class, there is no need to set the name, suit or value after construction. Remove the setters, and make the fields final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your `shuffle` method.

```
public void createSpades(){
    int l = 2;
    for(int i = 39; i < 48; i++){
        cardArray[i]=new Card(Integer.toString(l),"Diamonds",l);
        l++;
    }
    cardArray[48]=new Card("Jack","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[49]=new Card("Queen","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[50]=new Card("King","Diamonds",10);
    cardArray[51]=new Card("Ace","Spades",1);
}
```

The method creating **spades** is specifying the suit as **diamonds**. `createHearts` contains similar typos.

There is no point in having four methods to do basically the same thing. Aside from being overly verbose, you make mistakes in copying and pasting.

You can write a single method to create a suit:

```
public void createSuit(int offset, String name){
    for(int i = 2; i <= 10; i++){
        cardArray[offset + i - 2]=new Card(Integer.toString(i),name,i);
    }
    cardArray[offset + 9]=new Card("Jack",name,10);
    cardArray[offset + 10]=new Card("Queen",name,10);
    cardArray[offset + 11]=new Card("King",name,10);
    cardArray[offset + 12]=new Card("Ace", name,1);
}
```

Now, just invoke for each suit, passing the appropriate name and offset: if it works for one suit, it works for them all.

```
createSuit(0, "Clubs");
createSuit(13, "Diamonds");
createSuit(26, "Hearts");
createSuit(39, "Spades");
```

---

In terms of the `shuffle` method, that is incorrectly implemented to yield a fair distribution. A simpler approach would be to use `Collections.shuffle`:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cardArray));
```

Comment: (1+) Another simplification. Just use an ArrayList so you don't even need to worry about the offset.